# WordPress MySQL query inside custom widget

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I followed guidance from [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/) on creating a Widget in WordPress, they say to create a plugin widget which I have done and it does display `Hello World` as expected.

But now I want to run a mysqli query inside this widget. I can't find anywhere to supply information on this as I know the query I want to run is

`SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'facts'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$wpdb` by defining global inside your widget function,It has an instance of mysql connection

```
class YourWidget extends WP_Widget
{
   function widget($args, $instance)
    {
    global   $wpdb;
      $Results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts
       WHERE post_type = 'facts' AND post_status='publish'");
      var_dump($Results); /* to see what you got from query */
    }

}
```

[**Reference wpdb**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Comment: Although it's a valid query, it's better to use simple methods for this. They will have much less load on the database. See answer below

Answer (score 0):

Use the appropriate method:

```
$results = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'facts',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    ))

foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo $row->post_title;  
}
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts